# Update lines with same key from diffents lines source

Tags: sql, sap-iq

I have the following table Table1 :

```
numseq  Article     ID          Num1        Num2    Num3   Num4    Col07    Col08
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13          RCN03    9   
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13          RCN03    9   
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13          RCN03    9
```

The value of Col07 is false, there are one 5 character instead of 6.

Now, I have the corrected data in the table Table2

```
numseq  Article     ID              Num1        Num2    Num3   Num4    Col07     Col08
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13      RCN031    9   
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13      RCN035    9   
3023    F           242840794       4           12        1    13      RCN037    9
```

the key to update Table1.Col07 are all the others columns.

How can do the update ?

I use Sybase IQ 15.1.

I tried with row_number(), but the function is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTES: I don't have access to a IQ database; I do have access to a SQLAnywhere database; the functions used below do show up in the IQ reference manual; the proposed solution works in my SQLAnywhere database; net result is that the following should work in IQ ... >>crossing fingers<< ...

First some background:

1 - each record in a table has a unique row id that can be accessed via the `rowid(<table_name>)` function

2 - the `number()` function can be used to generate a unique number (starting with `1`) for a result set however, this function cannot be used in a sub-query or derived table (which means we can't incorporate derived tables in our UPDATE statement)

Gist of the solution:

1 - pull the desired rows from Table1 and Table2 into #temp tables, using the `number()` function to generate unique row numbers (starting from 1) for each set of #temp table records; also pull the `rowid()` for Table1

2 - write our UPDATE statement to reference our #temp tables, joining unique pairs of #temp table rows based on their row numbers (generated by the `number()` function), and join back to the main table via the `rowid()` values

Setup:

```
create table Table1 (numseq int, Article char(1), ID int, Num1 int, Num2 int, Num3 int, Num4 int, Col07 varchar(10), Col08 int)
go
create table Table2 (numseq int, Article char(1), ID int, Num1 int, Num2 int, Num3 int, Num4 int, Col07 varchar(10), Col08 int)
go

insert Table1 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN03',9)
insert Table1 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN03',9)
insert Table1 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN03',9)
go

insert Table2 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN031',9)
insert Table2 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN035',9)
insert Table2 values (3023,'F',242840794,4,12,1,13,'RCN037',9)
go

 numseq      Article ID          Num1        Num2        Num3        Num4        Col07      Col08
 ----------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9

 numseq      Article ID          Num1        Num2        Num3        Num4        Col07      Col08
 ----------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN031               9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN035               9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN037               9
```

Build/populate the #temp tables:

```
-- we'll use WHERE clauses in our 'select/into' statements in case you
-- are planning on processing just a subset of Table1 and/or Table2; and
-- while the 'order by' clauses aren't needed for this simple example, you 
-- will need to include them if you plan on updating multiple sets of 
-- duplicate rows at the same time (ie, you need to make sure the number() 
-- values match between sets of duplicate rows)

select rowid(Table1) as rid, number() as nbr, * into #t1 from Table1 where numseq = 3023 and Article = 'F' and ID = 242840794 and Num1 = 4 and Num2 = 12 and Num3 = 1 and Num4 = 13 and Col08 = 9
    order by numseq, Article, ID, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Col08
go
select                       number() as nbr, * into #t2 from Table2 where numseq = 3023 and Article = 'F' and ID = 242840794 and Num1 = 4 and Num2 = 12 and Num3 = 1 and Num4 = 13 and Col08 = 9
    order by numseq, Article, ID, Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Col08
go

select * from #t1
select * from #t2
go

 rid                  nbr         numseq      Article ID          Num1        Num2        Num3        Num4        Col07      Col08
 -------------------- ----------- ----------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
             68222976           1        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9
             68222977           2        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9
             68222978           3        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN03                9

 nbr         numseq      Article ID          Num1        Num2        Num3        Num4        Col07      Col08
 ----------- ----------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
           1        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN031               9
           2        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN035               9
           3        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN037               9
```

And now the UPDATE:

```
update  Table1

set     Table1.Col07 = #t2.Col07

from    Table1
join    #t1

        -- rowid() is unique and thus the only 'column' we need in the join between Table1 and itself (aka #t1)

on      rowid(Table1) = #t1.rid

        -- and the rest of the join columns between Table1 and #t1; optional 
/*
and     Table1.numseq      = #t1.numseq
and     Table1.Article     = #t1.Article
and     Table1.ID          = #t1.ID
and     Table1.Num1        = #t1.Num1
and     Table1.Num2        = #t1.Num2
and     Table1.Num3        = #t1.Num3
and     Table1.Num4        = #t1.Num4
and     Table1.Col08       = #t1.Col08
*/

join    #t2

        -- join on our number() values

on      #t1.nbr         = #t2.nbr

        -- and the rest of the join columns between #t1 and #t2; optional but
        -- provides an extra safety check to make sure we don't update records
        -- with the wrong values (eg, number() is generated in wrong order)

and     #t1.numseq      = #t2.numseq
and     #t1.Article     = #t2.Article
and     #t1.ID          = #t2.ID
and     #t1.Num1        = #t2.Num1
and     #t1.Num2        = #t2.Num2
and     #t1.Num3        = #t2.Num3
and     #t1.Num4        = #t2.Num4
and     #t1.Col08       = #t2.Col08
go

select * from Table1
go

 numseq      Article ID          Num1        Num2        Num3        Num4        Col07      Col08
 ----------- ------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN031               9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN035               9
        3023 F         242840794           4          12           1          13 RCN037               9
```

Comment: This seems to be what I need. I don't have access to the database right now, I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase supports `join` in `update`:

```
update t1
    set col7 = t2.col7
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.numseq = t2.numseq and
            t1.article = t2.article and
            . . . ;  -- I'm not sure which columns are needed for matching
```

Comment: OP's question mentions "the key to update Table1 is all the other columns". Here's the rest of the columns, based on the answer I was writing (that you ninja'd! :P): `t1.numseq=t2.numseq and t1.Article=t2.Article and t1.ID=t2.ID and t1.Num1=t2.Num1 and t1.Num2=t2.Num2 and t1.Num4=t2.Num4 and t1.Col08=t2.Col08`

Comment: @RobbieToyota, (I think) the point Gordon was trying to make is that we're dealing with 3 identical sets of join column values (Table1 and Table2), with the net result being that each row in Table2 will join with all 3 rows in Table1 (ie, a cartesian product); so, how do you ensure the 9 joins perform the desired 3 updates?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated how you match which row in Table1 with which row in Table2.

The proposed join columns have ***identical*** values in both tables; net result is that joining these 2 tables on the proposed join columns will cause a 9-row cartesian product (each row in Table2 matches each row in Table1).

I'm guessing the answer is something along the lines of ... for each row in Table2, join to any one row in Table1 ... with the whole purpose of this Q&A being how to limit each join to a single row in Table1.

And while there may be some slick means of doing this (NOTE: I don't work with IQ), I'm thinking the following may be a bit easier to implement and likely easier to understand:

```
begin tran

delete Table1 where ... >>conditions that match the 3 duplicate rows<< ...

insert Table1 select * from Table2 where ... >>conditions that match the 3 new rows<< ...

if no errors
    commit tran
else
    rollback tran
    generate additional error message ?
```

NOTE: Obviously (?) the above assumes that Table1 and Table2 have the same column set (same column names, same datatypes) ... which appears to be a valid assumption given the sample data you've provided.

Comment: "for each row in Table2, join to any one row in Table1" : that's exactly that. I don't really care which one from Table2 update which one from Table1, as it will be the same result.
I cannot do the delete/insert as I have in fact in Table1 other columns which are also all identical, but that I do not have in Table2.

Comment: yeah, I figured you'd come back with the comment about other columns in the table; assuming you have authority to create #temp tables ... I'm writing up another answer based on #temp table that should (knock on wood) do the job ... should be posted within the next 5-10 mins ...

Comment: I do have the possibility to create temp table